# MySQL DELETE statement with an user variable on a where-in clause?

Tags: mysql, where-clause, sql-drop, user-variables

Suppose I have this table:

```
drop table if exists t_user;
CREATE TABLE t_user (usr int, grp int);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (123456, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (111111, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (111311, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (122111, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (111111, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (111211, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (113211, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (115311, 5);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (122253, 3);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (222331, 6);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (118811, 3);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (112111, 6);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (213111, 6);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (343321, 7);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (114431, 2);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (115111, 8);
INSERT INTO t_user VALUES (324353, 3);
```

I want to run a query like this:

```
SELECT distinct @u := usr FROM t_user WHERE grp < 6;
```

To hold the ids of a bunch of users and use the result on a `delete` statement that will delete all those users:

```
delete from t_user where usr in ( @u );
```

The problem is that each time i run these two statements the first listed user is deleted and not all of them as I wanted.

**EDIT**

I can't simply run everything on a single query. I really want to know how to do it separately.

**EDIT²**

I followed @juergen instructions and tried using Temporary tables:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE t_temp (id int);

INSERT INTO t_temp SELECT DISTINCT usr FROM t_user WHERE grp < 6;

DELETE FROM t_user WHERE usr IN ( SELECT * FROM t_temp );

DROP TABLE t_temp;
```

---

I searched and found some similar answers, but i don't want to build a string and use it on my delete statement. I want something simpler.

- [mysql using user-defined variable in where clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10934939/mysql-using-user-defined-variable-in-where-clause)
- [MySQL: Using variable on a WHERE IN clause](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4439218/mysql-using-variable-on-a-where-in-clause)
- [In MySQL how do I use a user defined variable in a WHERE IN clause?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7815031/in-mysql-how-do-i-use-a-user-defined-variable-in-a-where-in-clause)

How to store the results from a query into a temporary table:
 - [Create table variable in MySQL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1524858/create-table-variable-in-mysql)

Comment: I am usually able to work around the `SQL Error (1093):` by wrapping the offending query in an inline view, that is, wrapping my subquery q (which references the table) inside another select, `SELECT * FROM ( q )`. The net effect is that MySQL is creating a temporary table just for the duration of the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

just do it in one query

```
delete from t_user 
where usr in (SELECT distinct usr FROM t_user WHERE grp < 6)
```

or even shorter

```
delete from t_user WHERE grp < 6
```

### Edit

A variable can only hold one entry. You could use a temp table to store the data you want.

### Edit 2

You could try a join instead of subquery. Haven't tried it though:

```
delete from t_user u1
inner join t_user u2 on u1.usr = u2.usr 
WHERE u2.grp < 6
```

Comment: I'm sorry, this is just an example.. if I try to do everything on a single query on my real problem I get this error: `SQL Error (1093): You can't specify target table 'my_table' for update in FROM clause`.

Comment: Anyway, I will try to use a temp table! Thanks

Comment: You could try a join instead of subquery. Maybe that works. See my update.

Comment: Actually i did the temp table thing and it solved my problem! Thank you!! I will update my question and put the solution!